# Move Drupal Profile2 field from one profile type to another

Tags: users

Use Case:

I have Profile2 module installed and enabled.

I have a Profile type called 'Main Profile' and it has a field (e.g. City) and different users have already entered value for the field.

I need to move this Profile2 field from one profile type ( Main Profile) to another new profile type (Career Profile).

After moving, the data initially entered by users for this field should be still present, without re-entering again.

Comment: Quick thought: see if [Field Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_tools) can help you with this.

Comment: if you have direct access to the database, you can convert them over to the new profile field